# How to count the number of documents in which an element of an object inside an array exists in a collection of Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a `MongoDB` `collection` called `Cards` containing structurally similar documents as illustrated below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("mongoid"),
"userName": "Har109",
"array1" : [
    {
        "id" : "11",
        "name" : "hello world",            
    }
    {
        "id" : "21",
        "name" : "bye world",            
    }
],
 "array2" : [
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "titanic",            
    }
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "name" : "avatar",            
    }
],
 "array3" : [
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "The Alchemist",            
    }
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "name" : "What is Zero",            
    }
]
}
```

I need to query: Count the number of Documents in the **collection** that matches **"array1.id"**, which I then can do it for all other arrays (e.g. **"array2.id", "array3.id"**)

What is the syntax for this kind of query in `MongoDB Compass`?

I tried: the pipeline to get all the documents where there is **array1**

```
 [{$count: 'array1'}]
```

But how do I add the condition of **where array1.id = "11"** to this pipeline on mongodb compass, where stages are done separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Count the number of Documents in the collection that matches "array1.id"

To find how many documents contain `array.id=x` you can run:

```js
db.collection.find({ "array1.id":"11" }).countDocuments()
```

Or using aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $match:{"array1.id":"11"} }, 
{ count:"array1" }
])
```

The algorithm traverses arrays automatically.

It won't find a document if the key does not exist.